# Reorder elements in array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
const array = [
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68c725c06ac987",
    customOrder: 1,
    name: "One",
  },
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68sgs25c06ac987",
    customOrder: 2,
    name: "Two",
  },
  {
    id: "5a252wfew32b68c725c06ac987",
    customOrder: 3,
    name: "Three",
  },
  {
    id: "5a25gffe32b68c725c06ac987",
    customOrder: 4,
    name: "Four",
  },
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68c725c06acfee7",
    customOrder: 5,
    name: "Five",
  },
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68c725c06ac556",
    customOrder: 6,
    name: "Six",
  },
]
```

When I update the `customOrder` of one of the objects and update the other objects based on `customOrder` So if I change index 2 to have a custom order of 4, I need to edit the `customOrder` of the other  elements so it the result would be:

```
const array = [
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68c725c06ac987",
    customOrder: 1,
    name: "One",
  },
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68sgs25c06ac987",
    customOrder: 2,
    name: "Two",
  },
  {
    id: "5a25gffe32b68c725c06ac987",
    customOrder: 3,
    name: "Four",
  },
  {
    id: "5a252wfew32b68c725c06ac987",
    customOrder: 4,
    name: "Three",
  }
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68c725c06acfee7",
    customOrder: 5,
    name: "Five",
  },
  {
    id: "5a2524432b68c725c06ac556",
    customOrder: 6,
    name: "Six",
  },
]
```

I'm thinking of using `array.slice()` or even using lodash `_.putAt()` but  I am trying to think of a simple way of achieving the best result

Comment: I think you have to use some sorting functions out there. Such as merge sort (just an example) and apply the sorting based on the `customOrder` key.

Comment: You already have the order in the array indices, so `customOrder` is superfluous. If you want to move something, just move it; then if you still need `customOrder`, relabel it with `array.forEach((x. i) => x.customOrder = i + 1)`.

Comment: Your question has 2 problem statements: **1.** Update related object. So when you update object at index `2` to `4`, you have to backtrack other object as well and change it. **2.** To maintain order, you will have to sort the list.

Comment: what if you change an order of not close related objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** to remove an item at an index and move it to the new index specified. Then update the `customOrder` using [**`forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

(You can take a copy of the array using spread syntax and use `map` if you don't want to mutate the original array)

```js
const array = [{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:1,name:"One",},{id:"5a2524432b68sgs25c06ac987",customOrder:2,name:"Two",},{id:"5a252wfew32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:3,name:"Three",},{id:"5a25gffe32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:4,name:"Four",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06acfee7",customOrder:5,name:"Five",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac556",customOrder:6,name:"Six",},]

function updateOrder(input, index, newIndex) {
  let copy = [...input];
  const removed = copy.splice(index, 1);
  copy.splice(newIndex, 0, removed[0]);
  return copy.map((a, i) => ({ ...a, customOrder: i+1 }))
}

console.log(updateOrder(array, 2, 3))
```

With mutation:

```js
const array = [{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:1,name:"One",},{id:"5a2524432b68sgs25c06ac987",customOrder:2,name:"Two",},{id:"5a252wfew32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:3,name:"Three",},{id:"5a25gffe32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:4,name:"Four",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06acfee7",customOrder:5,name:"Five",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac556",customOrder:6,name:"Six",},]

function updateOrderMutation(input, index, newIndex) {
  const removed = input.splice(index, 1);
  input.splice(newIndex, 0, removed[0]);
  input.forEach((a, i) => a.customOrder = i + 1)
  return input;
}

console.log(updateOrderMutation(array, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in four steps:

1. Use `Array.findIndex()` to locate the entry having the same value as the value you want to update at the given index.
2. Then change the value of this entry to the value of the item at the given index.
3. Then update the item at the given index with the new value.
4. Finally, swap the items. If there was no item with the new value, sort the array to make sure the item gets put at the right position.

**This version mutates the array:**

```js
const array = [{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:1,name:"One",},{id:"5a2524432b68sgs25c06ac987",customOrder:2,name:"Two",},{id:"5a252wfew32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:3,name:"Three",},{id:"5a25gffe32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:4,name:"Four",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06acfee7",customOrder:5,name:"Five",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac556",customOrder:6,name:"Six",},]

const swap = (arr, x, y) => [arr[x], arr[y]] = [arr[y], arr[x]];

function setOrder(arr, idx, value) {
  const idx2 = arr.findIndex(x => x.customOrder === value);
  if (idx2 >= 0) arr[idx2].customOrder = arr[idx].customOrder;
  arr[idx].customOrder = value;
  
  if (idx2 >= 0) swap(arr, idx, idx2);
  else arr.sort((a, b) => a.customOrder - b.customOrder);
  return arr;
}

setOrder(array, 2, 4);
console.log(array);

setOrder(array, 2, 10);
console.log(array);
```

**This version does not mutate the array:**

```js
const array = [{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:1,name:"One",},{id:"5a2524432b68sgs25c06ac987",customOrder:2,name:"Two",},{id:"5a252wfew32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:3,name:"Three",},{id:"5a25gffe32b68c725c06ac987",customOrder:4,name:"Four",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06acfee7",customOrder:5,name:"Five",},{id:"5a2524432b68c725c06ac556",customOrder:6,name:"Six",},]

const swap = (arr, x, y) => [arr[x], arr[y]] = [arr[y], arr[x]];

function setOrder(arr, idx, value) {
  const out = [...arr];
  const idx2 = out.findIndex(x => x.customOrder === value);
  if (idx2 >= 0) out[idx2] = { ...out[idx2], customOrder: out[idx].customOrder };
  out[idx] = { ...out[idx], customOrder: value };
  
  if (idx2 >= 0) swap(out, idx, idx2);
  else out.sort((a, b) => a.customOrder - b.customOrder);
  return out;
}

console.log(setOrder(array, 2, 4));
console.log(setOrder(array, 2, 10));
```

Comment: Just a minor pointer. You already have positions/index of both objects you are switching values for. Would it not make sense to switch objects instead of switching `customerOrder` and then sorting?

Comment: @Rajesh, you are totally right, that would be more optimal, I will update my answer